# What does the "hào" mean in "àihào" for "hobby"?

Tags: word, equivalent-phrase

Newbie here. It makes sense that "ài" means "love" in the context of hobbies; you're doing what you love. What does "hào" mean here, though? Is it just a strange pronunciation of the standard "hǎo"? Or is it more like "hào" is used to mean "lovely"? Thanks!

Comment: bkrs：hào
to be fond of
to have a tendency to
to be prone to
1) 动 爱、喜爱。
2) 名 心中所喜爱的事。

Comment: Hi @user6065, thanks for your comment. However, those examples appear to use "ài", not "hào". I already know the meaning of "ài".

Comment: 好(hào) also means [like to / fond of] beside['good / well]

Comment: Did you try any dictionaries before asking here?  Your answer is on http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php

Comment: ??? "those examples" explain the meaning of 好(hào) in Chinese

Comment: can anybody find the previous question asking for a list of characters undergoing change of pronunciation (in tone only) associated with change in word category? (users only supplied a very limited number of examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a character have multiple similar pronunciations, such as 好 with different tones, it can means different part of speech for the same/similar concept. This phenomenon is called [四声别义](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E8%81%B2%E5%88%A5%E7%BE%A9). For example:

- 好(hǎo，上声): adjective. good.

  好(hào，去声)：verb. like.
- 少(shǎo，上声): adjective. few.

  少(shào，去声): noun. young people.
- 骑(qí，阳平): verb. ride.

  骑(jì，去声): noun. rider (on horse).
- 教(jiāo，阴平): verb. teach.

  教(jiào，去声): noun. teaching.

In your question, 好 of 爱好 is a verb. The meaning is similar to 爱. Therefore, people combine these two characters to mean a verb, to like. 爱好 can also be [conjugated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjugation) (called 活用 in Chinese) as a noun, means hobby.

Comment: Chinese verbs can be conjugated?!

Comment: @Ludi Maybe calling it conjugation is inaccurate. What I mean is the part of speech of the words can be flexibly changed, such as noun -> verb, verb -> noun, adj -> verb, etc.

Comment: @HarrySummer Thanks for the very thorough answer! So, by using what would otherwise be a verb in a spot where noun _should_ be, you effectively conjugate the word? As in any other language, I'm sure this doesn't apply to all verbs, but it sounds similar to saying "I have my _likes_ and _dislikes,_" as opposed to "I _like_ some things and _dislike_ others." Same word, different part of speech simply by moving it.

Answer (score 1):

> [好](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/485/)
>
> [粵] hou2 | [國] hao3
>
> (1) [adj] good; fine; nice | [ant] 壞
>
> ....

~

> [好](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/485/)
>
> [粵] hou3 | [國] **hao**4
>
> [v] like; love; be fond of
>
> [v] be liable to; be likely to
>
> Example:
>
> 好(hao4)酒= like to drink
>
> 好(hao4)賭= like to gamble

**愛好**= 'love and like' = **interest/ hobby**